# Insert into sql table data with datetime and multiple rows using Python

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, python-3.5

I have created sql table with following code:

```
CREATE Table [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP](
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
    [ISO] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [pwrLoc] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [da] [int] NULL,
    [rt] [int] NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_daLMP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        (
            [DateTime] ASC,
            [ISO] ASC, 
            [pwrLoc] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 20) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a dataframe with columns as:

```
data.ix[1:4]
             DateTime    ISO  pwrLoc            DA             RT
1 2013-09-05 02:00:00  ERCOT  LZ_AEN            24.66          25.4100
2 2013-09-05 03:00:00  ERCOT  LZ_AEN            23.17          24.3750
3 2013-09-05 04:00:00  ERCOT  LZ_AEN            22.20          23.9225
4 2013-09-05 05:00:00  ERCOT  LZ_AEN            22.45          23.9625
```

I am trying the following to insert `data` into table `LMP`:

```
    values = [tuple(row) for row in data.values]
    dateInfoQry = 'insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values {}'.format(values)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL SERVER}; SERVER=2UA7491NP7\SQLEXPRESS')
    conn.execute(dateInfoQry)
```

I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with '(Timestamp('2013-09-05 01:00:00'), 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 28.31, 34.5325), (Timestamp('2013-09-05 02:00:00'), 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 24.' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '(Timestamp('2013-09-05 01:00:00'), 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 28.31, 34.5325), (Timestamp('2013-09-05 02:00:00'), 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 24.'. (102)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says the string is too long, probably the insert statement is not well formatted here. 
**Always try to use the single quotes for the string in the SQL Server.**

**The string has the "[]", so it needs formatting as well.**

```
 insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values [('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT LZ_AEN', '24.66', '25.4100'),('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT LZ_AEN', '24.66', '25.4100')]
```

So if we modify the code to something like this

```
values = [tuple(row) for row in data]
 dateInfoQry = 'insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values {}'.format(','.join(str(s) for s in values))
```

the insert statement looks pretty ok.

```
insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values ('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 4.66, 5.41),('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT', ' LZ_AEN', 24.66, 25.41)
```

It runs fine.

Give it a shot

Answer (score 4):

When I print your query `dateInfoQry`, I get this result:

```
insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values [('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 24.66, 25.41), ('2013-09-05 03:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 23.17, 24.375), ('2013-09-05 04:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 22.2, 23.9225), ('2013-09-05 05:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 22.45, 23.9625)]
```

You can see that there are still some square brackets because you include the list `values` as a whole (see `.format(values)`). However, if I build a string from that using `.format(','.join(str(v) for v in values))`, I get the following result which should work:

```
insert into [dataISO].[dbo].[LMP] (DateTime, ISO, pwrLoc, da, rt) values ('2013-09-05 02:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 24.66, 25.41),('2013-09-05 03:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 23.17, 24.375),('2013-09-05 04:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 22.2, 23.9225),('2013-09-05 05:00:00', 'ERCOT', 'LZ_AEN', 22.45, 23.9625)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

**SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF**

before your **insert into** it should help, as [] are similar to "" in SQL.